# Changing IP of python requests

Tags: python, networking

How do I change the IP of HTTP requests in python?
My friend built an API for a website, and sometimes it blocks certain IP's and so we need to change the IP of the request...  here is an example:

```
login_req = self.sess.post('https://www.XXX/YYY', params={...}
```

Now, each request that it sends, is through the computer's IP, and we need it basically to pass through an imaginary VPN.

Thanks for the help. If something isn't clear I will explain.

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than that. TCP (used by HTTP and HTTPS) creates a connection with TCP on the other end, and that depends on the IP (either IPv4 or IPv6) address because TCP uses a checksum based on the source and destination IP and TCP addresses. Simply changing the source IP address breaks that, and you would need to fix TCP also. Plus, the response back from TCP on the other end must be able to find your host based on the replaced IP address. That is why NAT is so complicated and resource intensive.

Comment: This is not how the Internet works. I suggest you do more reading to understand what IP addresses are and how they are used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**: you can't.

**Long answer**: it seems like you're misunderstanding how IP addresses work. Your IP address is the network address that corresponds to your computer - when you send a request to a server, you attach your IP as a "return address" of sorts, so that the server can send a response back to you.

However, just like a physical address, you don't get to choose what your IP address is – you live on a street, and that's your address, you don't get to change what the street is called or what your house number is. In general, when you send a request from your computer, the message passes through a chain of devices. For example:

```
Your computer --> Your router --> Your ISP --> The Server
```

In a lot of cases, each of these assigns a different IP address to whatever's below it. So, when your request passes through your router, your router records your IP address and then forwards the request through your ISP using *its own* IP address. Hence how several users on the same network can have the same IP address.

There are physical IP addresses, that correspond *directly* to devices, but there are a limited amount of these. Mostly, each Internet Service Provider has a few blocks of IP addresses that it can attach to things; an ISP can keep a specific IP address pointed to a specific computer all of the time, but they don't *have* to, and for many of their regular users, they don't.

Your computer has basically no power to determine what its own IP address is, basically. There's nothing python can do about that.

**Your Question**:

> we need [the request] basically to pass through an imaginary VPN.

It'd be easier to actually requisition a real proxy or VPN from somewhere and push your request through it. You'd have to talk with your internet service provider to get them to set something like that up for you specifically, and unless you're representing a reasonably big company they're unlikely to want to put in that effort. Most python libraries that deal with HTTP can easily handle proxy servers, so once you figure it out it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IP address from https://www.sslproxies.org/

For example,

```
import requests

response=requests.get("yourURL", proxies={'https': 'https://219.121.1.93:80', 'http': "http://219.121.1.93:80"})
```

The IP addresses on that site are pretty crappy and sometimes don't work, so it would be best to find a way to constantly scrape IP addresses from the site so you have a couple to try. Check out this article: https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/

warning: These should not be used for sensitive information as they are not secure. Don't use those IP addresses unless you are ok with anyone in the world knowing what your're doing.